# How to determine if this Differential Equation has a singular solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential, singular-solution

I found this Differential Equation $y'^2=16x^2$ and the text says it has a singular solution...

first they make an implicity derivation with respect to $y'$ then they have $2y'=0$. Therefore $y=constant$ and it proves that the D.E. has a singular solution but I can't figure out why it is correct.

Comment: Do you know how to find the singular solution  of a differential equation ?

Comment: No, I don't. I just have been seen some examples and trying to understand it. In some cases they find the singular solution just by observing the value of $y$ which make zero the D.E in others they apply the implicity derivation of the D.E...

Could you be so kind and explain me how to find the singular solution?

Answer (score 1):

Singular Solution is the Envelope of a Family of Curves. 
For an equation to be Singular Solution, it has to be common in both p-discriminant and c-discriminant and also has to satisfy the Differential Equation.

Here, 
Differential Equation is $ f(x, y, y’) = y'^2 - 16x^2 = 0 $ and 
General Solution is $ \phi(x, y, c) = (y-c)^2 - 4x^4 = 0 $

For finding p-discriminant, we find $ \frac {\partial f} {\partial y’} = 0 $ which gives $ 2y’ = 0 $ 
Now using the above, we need to eliminate $ y’ $ from $ f(x, y, y’) $ which gives $ x^2 = 0 $ which is a possible singular solution.

In this case, when we check whether $ x^2 = 0 $ satisfies the above given Differential Equation, we can see that it doesn’t ( $ \because y’ $ for this curve is tending to $\infty $ )

Graphically also, we can see that $ x^2 = 0 $ is not the envelope of the given family of curves. So, it’s not a singular solution.

Comment: I have the same feeling about it... It is not a singular solution but the text says it is... and the other guy @KenM said it is too. When I made the graph of it I didnt see that this singular solution envelope the given family curves too so I was confused.

Answer (score 0):

This is a separable equation of the form $y' = f(y) g(x)$. If $f(y_0) = 0$, then $y = y_0$ is an equilibrium solution to the differential equation. However, if there is no equilibrium solution passing through the point $y = y_0$, then $y = y_0$ is a singular solution. In this case, we have $f(y)$ is a constant, so as you stated, $f'(y) = 0$. Therefore it must be true that if $y = y_0$ is an equilibrium solution, it solves the equation $16x^2 = 0$ for all $x$, which is impossible. Therefore, it is a singular solution for any value of $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.